# Regular expression needed for PHP

Tags: php, regex

Can anybody tell me a regular expression to use within some PHP to find the following:

1. `<p>&nbsp;</p>` with any variation of white space between those tags
2. `<p><br/>` again with any variation of white space between those tags

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Oh god, there's so much blood http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454.... Should probably look into a parser instead.

Comment: @Robert - truly one of the most epic answers given on here... Lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straightforward (and folks, because he's asking for things with only whitespace between them, not nested tags or attributes or any of that, a parser isn't necessary in this case...)

```
/<p>\s+<\/p>/

/<p>\s+<br\/>/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse XML (or HTML) you should think about using a XML parser instead of regex. It would be more efficient.

PHP already contains an XML parser which is good for you :)

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net - XML Parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)

**On the same topic :**

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Hey, thanks. It’s actually for a parameter within an ExpressionEngine find and replace plugin, which I thought would be using PHP.

Comment: XML parser vs. regex isn't necessarily "more efficient" depending on what the task is. It's usually "more correct"; but in this very limited case scenario, regex actually works fine (and possibly faster).